# vim: how to get parentheses matching like in DrRacket et al.?

Tags: vim, plugins, parentheses

I want to my vim setup to color my parentheses as is default in the DrRacket IDE for Scheme.

I know how to set up parentheses matching using the built-in `MatchParen` hlgroup but I think it's going to be hard to use that to good effect.

DrRacket highlights matching parenthese as follows:

- make the background of the parentheses and all their contents a bit darker
- also do this for any parentheses inside the parentheses
- only do this for parentheses where the cursor is (like `MatchParen`)

Take a look at this screenshot to get a clearer idea what I mean:
[image]

This way you get a good visual feedback when writing paren-heavy languages such as Lisp.

Does a plugin exist that implements this behaviour? Or do you have tips on how I could 
implement this myself?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen a plugin implementing the staggered background coloring (and that would be difficult with low-color terminals and Vim shortcomings in the syntax highlighting), but a popular plugin is [rainbow_parentheses.vim - Better Rainbow Parentheses](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3772), which uses different colors for each set of parens.

Comment: yes, I'm using that plugin now. but it cannot be extended to do the background colors...

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the same thing, so I forked the script and changed it accordingly.

Let me know if it works for you (and don't forget to set the colours to match your colour theme, as the defaults are unlikely to be pleasant!)

https://github.com/cbranch/rainbow_parentheses.vim

This script doesn't highlight on the cursor's position, but hopefully it is not difficult to merge the behaviour of the MatchParen plugin with this one. I personally don't care for it, so that is an exercise for others :)

Comment: did not work for me. I just works the same as the default rainbowparentheses on my machine. I'm using vim 7.4.52.